# Was Batman gay according to his creators?

Tags: dc

I recall reading that one of Batman’s creators once stated that Batman was gay, but I can't find any reference to that (it was some blog).

Was it made up, or did someone who created Batman for DC actually say that Batman was homosexual?

Comment: To the downvoter: this is a valid question, as DVK's interesting answer shows. I can understand how this could be seen as a troll attempt, but it based on (a misunderstanding of) an actual interview of one of the writers of Batman!

Comment: In the other sense of the word, no. Batman is not happy. ; )

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To expand on my earlier comment, the short answer is "No". Longer answer is "he was quoted to say that but he didn't actually say that".

That blog you read must have been referring to a Playboy interview by [Grant Morrison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grant_Morrison) (who wrote Batman for DC since 1989 as far as I know).

He was once interviewed by Playboy about his book. He told them that Batman could be seen as gay if some of his traits were taken to extreme; but that he was NOT; which Playboy inverted. Here's his later [explanation](http://www.newstatesman.com/blogs/voices/2012/09/grant-morrison-gay-batman-superheroes-wonder-woman) (emphasis mine):

> He's not joking. One particular interview, published in Playboy, not only made the newspapers around the world, but resulted in Morrison being denounced on Brazilian television. It was that now infamous soundbite, in which he said Batman -
>
> “Is gay!” he finishes. “**But the thing is, it was the opposite of what I said**. But Playboy had it in as the most sensationalised version, they didn't take off the bit at the end... Because it was all from the book, it was from an interview I did last year for Supergods. **And basically I said what I said in the book, that you can easily dial up the black-leather-fetishistic-night-dwelling aspects of Batman, and the masculinity of Batman, and get a pretty good gay Batman. But as I said, ultimately he's not gay because he has no sex life, really**. All he is is an adventurer.. sometimes they show him with girls, sometimes he never seems to be going out with girls.
>
> “But they just took off the cool sound-bite which is 'Batman is utterly, utterly gay, says Morrison'! That was it, I had to deal with that – people were really f#cking mad at me for that one.”

I'm not aware of any other DC writers making claims on the topic either.

Answer (score 9):

As an addendum to DVK's answer, I'll add that Batman was created by Bob Kane and Bill Finger in 1939 and there is no real evidence that he was gay. (Rick Veitch explored alternate concepts in that avenue under the guise of Bratpack and other books.) Referring to any writers since then as a creator is incorrect. Many have added to the history, and the back-story has been changed a couple times, but as much as I am a Grant Morrison fan, he can not be called a creator of Batman. He is brilliant at reinterpreting and re-contextualizing characters. His 80's work on Animal Man and Doom Patrol set the stage for his newer work on other existing characters.

Comment: Good point. I read "creators" as "people writing Batman comics".